# NSOperationQueue operations filteredArrayUsingPredicate error

Tags: iphone, ios, nspredicate, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I have class `MyOperation : NSOperation` with `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *oID;`

And sometimes I need to cancel operation with specific `oID`. I'm trying to do this:

```
NSArray *operations = operationQueue.operations;
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"oID == %@", _specificID]];
NSArray *arrayOperations = [operations filteredArrayUsingPredicate: predicate];
```

and get error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "oID == 0f5db97b-f127-4425-ad79-451d1f204016"'
```

Is it possible to filter operation from NSOperationQueue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are formatting a string, then sending that to the Predicate constructor method.  It's already a formatter, and knows how to format the data you give it.

Basically, you need the format to look like:

```
oID == "0f5db97b-f127-4425-ad79-451d1f204016"
```

but you are getting

```
oID == 0f5db97b-f127-4425-ad79-451d1f204016
```

If you use the formatter by itself, you should get past this issue...

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"oID == %@", _specificID];
```

NOTE: The predicate formatter knows it should handle strings specially, and automatically adds the extra quotation characters when you pass a string to be formatted by `%@`'

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that the operations.queue is a mutable array (logging its class returns this '__NSArrayM'). What you should try is:

```
NSArray *operations = [NSArray arrayWithArray:operationQueue.operations];
```

That said, some operation may have completed (and been removed from the mutable queue) by the time the predicate is applied to it.